Ubuntu 24 VM "systemd-logind crashed with SIGABRT" error while running Gala TownStar v2 Node
I am somewhat newb to Linux but this is my 5th or so Linux VM I've ever setup so I have some experience here. I have an Ubuntu 24 VM running in Oracle VirtualBox running in a Windows 11, 8 core, 32GB RAM PC. The Gala TownStar v2 Node that I am running on this PC requires a 2 core, 8GB RAM, 40GB hard drive space to run and so I setup the VM with exactly those specs. I have this VM bridged on the network so that it has its own IP because I also am running another instance of that node on that actual PC, not the VM. So the PC has the node running, then in a VM running on that same PC, I have another instance of that node running.
This seems to work well but once or twice a day I notice that the node running in the VM is down! When I go to the VM I just run sudo gala-node status and that is all it takes for the node to come back alive. The node running directly on my PC has never gone down. So daily I go to the dashboard and when it's down, I run that command... but this means it could be hours before I notice. Every so often when I go back to the VM to run that command, I see Ubuntu with an error that it wants to report, when I look at the details, the message is

systemd-logind crashed with SIGABRT

I am not certain that this error is the reason for the node going down, but I have nothing else to go on. I found this page with some discussion about it and possible solutions but none of that seemed to work for me. Someone suggested I go back to Ubuntu 20.04, but before I spend time on that, does anyone have any suggestions? BTW, I tried running an "every 5 min" crontab to run that status command, but that either doesn't work or I am not certain that it's doing the thing. sudo crontab -l shows that */5 * * * * sudo gala-node status is there, but I'd love for it to spit out the output to my console, I think I could have the output of that crontab go to a file, so that's probably my next step.
Edit: Installed Ubuntu 20.04 and am now getting much more frequent error of the same type, like every 5 minutes! The exact error message there is: "systemd-resolved" crashed with SIGBRT in epoll_wait() Also a recent output from one of the many times it crashed, Ubuntu 20.04: 

You lack elementary Linux skills. Please educate yourself or take a school. This is not the right place to ask newbie questions. But to give you one hint, using crontab in that way is a bad idea and using a sudo command within a crontab is also a bad idea. If you want to have a repeated command, showing up on console, for every 5 minutes refreshing, use watch -n 300 $YOUR_COMMAND.

Is "TownStar" something CPU-heavy or RAM-heavy? All of the kernel messages in your VM console hint at the VM being very starved of resources; without seeing the system logs (please check system logs via journalctl -b) I suspect that systemd-logind also gets a SIGABRT from not meeting systemd's watchdog timer rather than from actually crashing as such, which is something that happens if the system is out of RAM and too busy swapping in/out...

(I don't agree that crontab is a bad idea here  necessarily – cron output traditionally used to go to email for this exact purpose – but in this specific case it's just as likely to fail to run as the already-running services.)

After I noticed that the error in Ubuntu 20.04 was complaining about the CPUs, I started messing around with more CPUs and even adding another type of node to the same VM. Conclusion: to run 2 different types on an Ubuntu 24 VM (20.04 performed worse) needed 6 CPUs (3 physical, 3 virtual) to be stable.
